# 3D transformations on rendered HTML in flash?

Tags: html, flash, dynamic

I'm trying to figure out if this is possible to execute on a dynamic page.
http://salesdemo.unicast.com/vla/asset/demo/604_150148/index.html

Basically, after all the page has been rendered, Flash needs to take the rendered page and apply 3D transformations to it, and at the end, restore the original rendered page.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't expect Flash to render any page's HTML the way your browser does. Not only are Flash's HTML rendering capabilities limited to text (inside a `TextField`) but you will also run into XSS security locks when trying to download the webpage from the external site.

I'd say the best you can do is to render the HTML to an image (using something like [thumbalizr](http://thumbalizr.com/)), load that into Flash and do the 3D transform on it. Of course, this may or may not work for you depending on what your ultimate goal is.

Comment: this was the approach i was leaning towards. Didn't end up having to execute this dynamically but thanks for the answer :)